# replace callback function with matches

Tags: javascript

need to replace `<wiki>this page</wiki>` to `<a href='wiki/this_page'>this page</a>`
using callback function:

```
text = text.replace(/<wiki>(.+?)<\/wiki>/g, function(match)
    {
        return "<a href='wiki/"+match.replace(/ /g, '_')+"'>"+match+"</a>";
    }
);
```

result is that tag `<wiki>` is preserved (full match) - `<a href='wiki/<wiki>this_page</wiki>'><wiki>this page</wiki></a>`

Is there a way to get matches[0], matches[1] as in PHP's `preg_replace_callback()`?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The [`replace` function's callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) takes the matches as parameters.

For example:

```
text = text.replace(/<wiki>(.+?)<\/wiki>/g, function(match, contents, offset, input_string)
    {
        return "<a href='wiki/"+contents.replace(/ /g, '_')+"'>"+contents+"</a>";
    }
);
```

(The second parameter is the first capture group)

Comment: I think the answer is okay, but it is too brief.   Also the order of the last two parameters to the matching function seems to be incorrect.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter
where it explains that there are a varying number of parameters received by the matching function depending on the number of "parenthesized submatch[es]".

Comment: Note that someone corrected the example after the comment by @user2367418 - the example is currently correct, with one group `(.+?)` in the regex, and one parameter `contents` for the captured group. (it is a rather confusing and fragile API, where the parameter positions change based on the number of groups in the regex - see [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) of the MDN docs)