# Replace only part of match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that currently looks like this:

```
/((0{32})([0-1]{48}){16})/
```

Basically, match "0" 32 times, then "0" or "1" 48 times, then that pattern 16 times. Seems to be working for `str.match()`.

What I'm trying to do is replace the "0"s matched *only in that first part* (the 32, each of the 16 times) with "1", but not the "0"s matched in the second part (the `[0-1]` range of 48).

I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to accomplish that today.

The regex pattern is separately generated, but the string it matches will always contain only "0"s and "1"s. Yes, I'm sure this seems weird, but this is exactly what I need to happen.

Comment: use a replace() function and inside of it, replace() the text in the first group match, returning the rest un-altered

Comment: Please post input and expected output.

Comment: @noob That would be pages (16,000 character string length). But basically, a very long string of nothing but "0"s and "1"s, with the end result being matched zeros converted to ones.

Comment: @RandyHall: In such cases make a [pastebin](https://www.pastebin.com) and add it's like to your question.

Comment: @noob unfortunately blocked by my employer. But it is good info for later, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a positive lookahead to assert that the 32 zeros must be followed by the 48 ones and zeros, but not actually capture them.  For instance:

```
/((0{32})(?=([0-1]{48}){16}))/
```

Comment: @Toni yup. Lookaheads are no problem. Lookbehinds are another story, however.

Comment: Almost. It appears to be replacing the matched 32 with a single "1" - using like `str.replace(myReg, "1")` Since the 32 might be a different length (generated number) is there an easy way to tell it to replace each of the matched "0" instead of all?

Comment: Yes, there are ways of doing that.  Not in the search pattern, but in the way that you perform the replacements.  For instance, you could use a [callback method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3395843/1359668) to customize the replacement.  In the callback, check the length of the captured text and make sure that your replacement is the same length as that.