# Node.js: Wrap all headings with a div tag

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

How do I iterate through all headings in HTML and wrap them with divs with a unique in node.js?

I cannot use a regex replace as the div ids need to be unique

Cheerio seems to be the best framework for web scraping in node.js, but I do not see a way of solving this use case

Comment: A simple regex would be enough, right?

Comment: What have you tried already? Seems like you're asking us to write the code for you...

Comment: @lumio No, as the div ids will need to be unique

Comment: @jakerella I have experimented with cheerio but there does not seem to be a way of doing this.  I can see how to edit an item, but not wrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace callback function with matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395843/replace-callback-function-with-matches)

Comment: You can achieve unique ids with regex replace too

Comment: @lumio - I need to store the ids also

Comment: Store them in an array? No problem :) Don't get me wromg, I used cheerio for HTML manipulation already, but this could be done with a simple search/replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so as far as I understand is, you want to wrap all headlines (h1-h6) with a div where its ID is stored in an array (or so).

You can of course use `cheerio` (see solution at the bottom), but I think with similar effort this can be achieved with RegEx as well.

```
// I define the HTML in a simple constant for now.
// Use it for both solutions.
const html = `
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Text</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>

      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>

      <h2>This is a small HTML example</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
`;
```

The first solution with RegEx:

```
// Use html-constant from above!
function convertHeadlines( html ) {
  const r = /(<h\d>[\s\S]+?<\/h\d>)/g; // See https://regex101.com/r/jNjbXh/1 for explanation
  const ids = [];
  // Replace every match and wrap it with a new DIV.
  const output = html.replace( r, ( match ) => {
    const newId = `headline${ ids.length + 1 }`;
    ids.push( newId );
    return `<div id="${ newId }">${ match }</div>`;
  } );

  return {
    ids,
    output,
  };
}

const result = convertHeadlines( html );
console.log( result );
```

This results in an object, giving you all ids and the new HTML.

---

Here the solution with `cheerio` - similar approach:

```
// Use html-constant from above!
const cheerio = require( 'cheerio' );
function convertHeadlinesWithCheerio( html ) {
  const $ = cheerio.load( html );
  const headlines = $( 'h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6' );
  const ids = [];
  headlines.each( function ( i, elem ) {
    const newId = `headline${ ids.length + 1 }`;
    ids.push( newId );
    $( this ).wrap( `<div id="${ newId }"></div>` );
  } );

  return {
    ids,
    output: $.html(),
  }
}

const result = convertHeadlinesWithCheerio( html );
console.log( result );
```

Comment: Great answer - interesting that the cheerio solution adds an ID to the Heading as well

Comment: The regex version does not appear to wrap the headline with a div

Comment: [I created a CodePen here](https://codepen.io/lumio/pen/jLmLJK) which uses the RegEx solution. And what do you mean that the cheerio solution adds an ID to the headline as well. It shouldn't do that. At least when I tested it. What NodeJS and cheerio version are you using?