# Detect problems with ellipsis using JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have some strings that are meant to contain three dots...but sometimes they contain only two dots in a row, or more than three dots in a row. I'm trying to detect the strings that have too many or too few dots.

This regex works, but only in Chrome:
`/((?<![.])[.]{2}(?![.])|(?<![.])[.]{4,}(?![.]))/g`

Other browsers' JavaScript RegExp engines don't support lookbehinds, and from what I've read, I can't rewrite this to make the lookbehind a lookahead, because the the regex already has a lookahead.

Perhaps I don't need a RegExp-based solution at all? I'm not seeing it, though.

Strings matching pattern:

```
I have too many dots....and that's a problem
................
...Hey, that's not going to work..
```

Strings not matching pattern:

```
Here's a big success ...and that's great!
0.30.
```

Comment: Are you going through a replace process or match only?

Comment: It would probably be a lot simpler to flip this and only match strings that *do* contain 3 dots in a row. Would you be able to work with that?

Comment: Why don't you just replace all instances of 2+ dots with `...` like [this](https://regex101.com/r/xTIbW7/1): `\.{2,}`. I think you're just overthinking this whole scenario.

Comment: @ctwheels He also wants to match strings that only contain 2 dots in a row, which would require something more complex (if lookaround isn't an option) like `(?:[^.]|^)\.{2}(?:[^.]|$)`

Comment: @CAustin but it's the same `\.{2,}` matches two dots in a row.

Comment: Oh, right. I don't think he's search/replacing though, just validating? Not 100% sure from the question.

Comment: @CAustin I see what you mean. I'll wait for the OP to comment. If I'm wrong in assuming it's a simple replace, I'll remove my answer, but I don't see why they would be trying to match the locations rather than substitute the characters based on the question's topic/context.

Comment: I guess it's a little unclear what the result should be. We need clarification from the OP.

Comment: I'm only matching (validating), as @CAustin said

Comment: The replace idea seems like a good one: if there is a difference between the original string and the replace() output, that would mean there was a match, yes? Maybe your answer could be adapted @ctwheels

Comment: I suppose you could just do the replacement, save it to a variable, then check if the new and original values are equal. Probably better to just go with the more complex pattern, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this. Just target all locations of 2 dots or more and forget about not matching `...` since that's your replacement anyway.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/xTIbW7/2)

```
\.{2,}
```

Replacement: `...`

```js
var s = `I have too many dots....and that's a problem
................
...Hey, that's not going to work..

Here's a big success ...and that's great!
0.30.`
var r = /\.{2,}/g

console.log(s.replace(r, '...'))
```

Comment: If I wanted to do matching, just for a check, it looks like `s.replace(/\.{2,}/g,'...') !== s` would work, yes? I think this is a rather niche problem I'm trying to solve, and I'm very happy with this simple solution.

Comment: @MartinBurch you could use a callback function to test whether the match equals the substitution. If that test is true you’ve matched `...`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395843/replace-callback-function-with-matches for more info