# Strategies to identify non-capitalized proper nouns in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm working on a tool to help me format texts sent by users, and one of its functions should be to detect lowercase proper nouns or acronyms, so I can set some of their characters to uppercase accordingly.

For example:

- Identify "usa" and set it to "USA";
- Identify "united states of america" and set it to "United States of America";

A single string used as input has an average of **200 words** in **40 lines**. I'm using **javascript**.

I know I probably cannot find **all** of the existing proper nouns and acronyms, considering my input may even come in multiple different languages.
However, I would like some suggestions to try to maximize the detection of incorrect lowercase words while keeping a good performance.

My first strategy was to build an array of common used acronyms and proper nouns, I filled this array with 260 words I could come up. Then I check the input string line by line, using a regex to try and find each of the words from the array.

Needless to say, it ended up being a bit slow, since it will usually do at least 10400 comparisons per string if we consider only the `for` loops.

Code is down below:

```
function format(text) {
    var input = text.split("\n");
    var result = "";
    for (var line in input) {
        result += handleExceptionsAndTypos(input[line]);
    }
    return result;
}

function handleExceptionsAndTypos(s) {
    // getExceptionsAndTypos() returns the list of common proper nouns and acronyms
    var exceptionsAndTypos = getExceptionsAndTypos();
    var w;

    for (w in exceptionsAndTypos) {
        if (exceptionsAndTypos.hasOwnProperty(w)) {
            s = s.replace(new RegExp("(^|[^A-Za-z\u00E0-\u00FC])" + w + "(?=([^A-Za-z\u00E0-\u00FC]|$))", 'ig'), "$1"+ exceptionsAndTypos[w]);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Obs: The regex got a bit complicated, because the word boundary `\b` won't recognize accented characters ("á", "à", "ç", etc), so I had to use things such as `(^|[^A-Za-z\u00E0-\u00FC])` as a replacement. Any suggestions to this problem are welcome as well.

Comment: Even if you can't find a better solution, you should definitely create the `RegExp`'s in advance and cache them (as I understand, `getExceptionsAndTypos()` always returns the same result), that can shave a bit of time off.

Comment: Is not clear how `getExceptionsAndTypos();` is internally working. But you are calling it once for every line of text. You can do it only once. For instance converting  `var exceptionsAndTypos` in a global variable, ...among other options.

Comment: I would split the input into words, than check each words seperately, maybe use some kind of tree to speed up searching for patterns.

Comment: *even come in multiple different languages* — proper noun capitalization is an English convention. German capitalizes *all* nouns. Other languages have their own rules, not to mention their own alphabets or other glyph sets.

Comment: Why don't you combine your list on `|` and put it in a capture group such that you end up with a regex like `(^|[^a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])(my|joined|list|here)(?=(?:[^a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]|$))`. Then use a [replace with callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395843/replace-callback-function-with-matches) to get the value of the second capture group. No for loop, the regex will just go through all options until one is found (if one is found) and then your callback can search the original array and replace it with the new value. Not sure how speed will be impacted but worth a shot to test

Comment: @pointy also one should note that there are *nominalisierte Verben* (= nominalized verbs) e.g. `laufen` (walk) and `das Laufen`, so it needs to be determined by the context the word is in

Comment: @JonasW. yes, and many many other such details. The OP has embarked on a natural language interpretation project, or else something that won't work very often

Comment: If you plan to only use Chrome, the word boundary is no longer an issue. To match a whole word, you may use `"(?<![\\p{L}\\p{N}_])" + w + "(?![\\p{L}\\p{N}_])"` thanks to the lookbehind and Unicode category classes support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works `(?=usa|united|states|america)(?:([a-z])([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]+))`

Please note that you need to build a group with all the 260 words.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qfLOMZ/1)

Comment: How does it work with: ‘this document states we are united against the enemy .’

Comment: @Mark_M, I also noticed that the requirement is to convert `usa` to `USA`, which will not work with the current regex. I feel the regex could be modified to `^(?=usa|united states of america)([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]+(?:\s[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]+)*)$` [(See Demo)](https://regex101.com/r/qfLOMZ/2) to find the noun and as @ctwheels suggested in a comment to the question, use replace with callback function to look in exceptionsAndTypos and replace the value

Comment: @Matt.G, this last answer worked perfectly. Thanks for the help, guys!

Answer (score -1):

I had came up with a simple idea, but I don't really know by how much is going to improve the performance. Moreover, this basic idea would normally work only on acronyms.

Firstly, you will categorize the nouns by their length, and then for every word in a given line that you want to compare, you will use its length to decide in which category you should start comparing, then using some other factor of categorizing (e.g. first letter) you will cut off much more words so you will narrow the  proper nouns and acronyms to use against that word.

A brief example would be as following:

```
let str = "usa is where ..."

let acr_list = {
    2: ["FR", "AR", "UK", "NB" ...etc],
    3: ["USA" ...etc]
    ...
}

str.split(" ").foreach(w => {
    if (arc_list[w.length].indexOf(w.toUpperCase() !== -1) {
        //Do whatever you want to do 
    }
});
```

I don't know if this idea can be more enhanced .. but any suggestion is welcome of course.

Comment: There are a lot of nice solutions if we know all lookups will be for single words. But the OP wants to find things like “united states of america” too. You won’t find that if you tokenize everything by splitting on space. Even if this would work, why not out all words in the first level of the hash and just look them up directly. It would be faster.

Comment: I've already stated that this solution would work only for acronyms not for nouns such as "united states of america".

Comment: Then it doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: I could agree that my contribution doesn't answer the question, but why the -1 anyway ?