# Javascript method to convert string value

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help me to write a JS method which takes a String value like

/Content/blockDiagram/0/bundle/0/selectedBundle

/Content/blockDiagram/1/bundle/1/selectedBundle

/Content/blockDiagram/0/bundle

and convert it to 

/Content/blockDiagram[1]/bundle[1]/selectedBundle

/Content/blockDiagram[2]/bundle[2]/selectedBundle

 /Content/blockDiagram[1]/bundle

It is basically taking the number in the path and increment it by 1 and then changing the structure of the string.

My attempt

```js
function setReplicantPartListOptions(list) {
  list = "/" + list;
  var index = list.lastIndexOf("/");
  var tempString = list.substring(0, index);
  var index2 = tempString.lastIndexOf("/");
  var initialString = list.substring(0, index2);
  var result = tempString.substring(index2 + 1, index) var middlevalue = parseFloat(result) + 1
  var lastString = list.substring(index, list.length);
  list = initialString + "[" + middlevalue + "]" + lastString;
  return list;
}
```

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Comment: find the value between `/ number /` and check if it's a number then change it to `[number] + /`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Please update the question instead of posting unformatted code. I copied your code to the question for you

Answer (score 2):

simple regular expression with  capture group with replace

```js
var str = "/Content/blockDiagram/0/bundle/0/selectedBundle"
var updated = str.replace(/\/(\d+)/g, function (m, num) {
  var next = +num + 1; // convert string to number and add one
  return "[" + next + "]";  //return the new string
})
console.log(updated)
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought :)

Answer (score 2):

`String.replace(RegExp, callback(match, contents))` is the [callback version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395843/replace-callback-function-with-matches) of `String.replace()`.

In my case, the first parameter of callback function is the result/match. It takes the match and converts it to number using `+` operator, and then increment it by one. Finally, I add `[ ]` around the value and return it!

```js
let str = "/Content/blockDiagram/0/bundle/0/selectedBundle"
console.log( 
    str.replace(/\b\d+\b/g, match => `[${ +match + 1 }]`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "/Content/blockDiagram/0/bundle/0/selectedBundle"
console.log(
  str.replace(/\/(\d+)\//g, function(_,num) { return `[${++num}]`})
)
```