# Transform text inside parentheses to uppercase

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

What I'm am trying to do is get the html text inside parentheses and transform it to uppercase. I want the output to be:

```
Cat (IVA)
Dog (MANGO) etc.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
// Transform text inside parentheses to upper case
let petName = $(".petName").text();
let regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;

for (var i = 0; i < petName.length; i++) {
  let regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
  regExp.replace(petName[i].toUpperCase())
}


html
    <div>
      <h1 class="petName">Cat (Iva)</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1 class="petName">Dog (Mango)</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1 class="petName">Puppy (Mara)</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: missing a dot before `toUpperCase()`

Comment: @theblackgigant, thanks, but it seems that still does not work

Comment: String objects areimmutable in JS. `regExp.replace(…)` does not change the original, it only _returns_ the altered result. You still need to “write” this back into your HTML elements now, if you want to see the effect.

Comment: Oh, and you are not even selecting any elements to begin with - the selector `.petName h1` matches `h1` elements that are _descendants_ of an element with the class `petName`

Comment: @CBroe, yes I got it messed up in here. a codepen: https://codepen.io/shegraywolf/pen/eYJZmwE?editors=1010

Comment: You can not call `toUpperCase` while replacing like this either, you need to use a callback function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395843/replace-callback-function-with-matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple things wrong here:

- String objects are immutable in JS. `regExp.replace(…)` does not change the original, it only returns the altered result.`
- You are not selecting any elements to begin with. The selector `.petName h1` matches `h1` elements that are descendants of an element with the class `petName`
- you can not directly call a function while replacing, you need to do this via a callback function, that gets the match(es) passed to it.

---

```
let $petNames = $("h1.petName")

$petNames.each(function() {
  $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/, function(match) {
     return match.toUpperCase()
  } ) )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. :)

```js
$(".petName").each(function(i, el) {
  const text = el.innerText;
  
  const strToReplace = text.match(/(\(.*\))/)[0];

  el.innerText = text.replace(strToReplace, strToReplace.toUpperCase());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 class="petName">Cat (Iva)</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 class="petName">Dog (Mango)</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 class="petName">Puppy (Mara)</h1>
</div>
```